# Blazor css navigation active status

Tags: css, blazor, mudblazor

I have some **anchor** tags(tried with **navlink** tags also) in a menu. For any link, there can be **active(clicked)**, **hover** or **normal** styles(defined in css).

I have separate styles for all 3. They display normally for normal styles(not hovered, not clicked/other tag clicked) and hover.

Now, I want active styles to STAY when I click an anchor. But they disappear when I stop holding the mouse button.(meaning those styles stay for that clicked link when I have clicked on it and holding the mouse button. When I stop holding the button, styles disappear).

The color changes to blue instead, and goes to other links when clicked, which is how it should be for the styles. But I am not understanding where is that color coming from either.

Comment: perhaps check the CSS rules being applied in the inspector?

Comment: I tried that, the active status disappears when choosing element inspect mode.

Comment: perhaps try selecting "Toggle Element State" in the inspect window